# array was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, g++

I am written a c++ program and in it used `array` object and included `<array>` header file but when I try to compile it using `g++` it return a lot of error messages saying that "array was not declared in this scope". What can be wrong with it.
Program is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

const int Seasons = 4;
const array<string, Seasons> Snames =
 {"spring", "summer", "fall", "winter"};

void fill(array<double, Seasons>* pa);
void show(array<double, Seasons> da);

int main()
{
array<double, Seasons> expenses;
fill(&expenses);
show(expenses);

return 0;
}

void fill(array<double, Seasons>* pa)
{
 for(int i = 0; i < Seasons; i++)
 {
    cout << "Enter " << Snames[i] << " expenses: ";
    cin >> *pa[i];
 }
}

void show(array<double, Seasons> da)
{
double total = 0.0;
cout << "\nEXPENSES\n";

 for(int i = 0; i < Seasons; i++)
 {
    cout << Snames[i] << ": $" << da[i] << endl;
    total += da[i];
 }
cout << "Total Expenses: $" << total << endl;
}
```

Comment: What about the namespace? Did you call it `std::array` in your code? Better yet, can you **show your code**?

Comment: I don't know! No one knows. You know why? Because you didn't show your code.

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Please try to compile the following code which is correctly compiled by VC++ 2012: #include <array> using namespace std; int main() { array<int, 5> a; a[1] = 9; return 0; }

Comment: Your code should be more concise to highlight the point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most likely reason why your program does not compile is that the `<array>` header is not compatible with pre-C11 compilers. Add

```
-std=c++0x
```

to the flags of your g++ to enable C++11 support. Once you do, you'd get a [different error](http://ideone.com/1QInrL), because line 28 should be

```
cin >> (*pa)[i];
```

(**EDITED**; original answer suggested a missing reference to `std::`)

Comment: @XinHua Please see the edit. Your program runs now ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/TbsHew)).

Answer (score 2):

add either one of the below after the #include:

```
using namespace std;
using std::array;
```

Comment: You missed the most important fix for the issue here.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: You missed to write *why* those lines solve the problem, and that `array` is member of namespace `std`, which is the most important part of the answer. A.k.a. fully qualifying name as `std::array`.

Comment: Bleh, not going to argue with people failing to distinguish language newcomer from regular coder.

Answer (score 1):

It's called `std::array` - it's prefixed with `std::` namespace qualifier, like every standard library class or function [template].